# None of the HTML elements are working (can't type in input), forms are not aligned side by side

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
/* SHIPPING FORM 
===============================================================================================
*/
::placeholder{
  font-weight: 600;
}


#shipping-form{
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width: 440px;
}

.input-element{
  background-color: #0C0C0D !important;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.full-length{
  width: 440px !important;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}
.right{
  float: right;
}

#shipping-title{
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#shipping-title-wrapper{
  margin-left: 170px;
}

#shipping-icon{
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

/* BILLING FORM 
===============================================================================================
*/

#billing-form{
  float: right;
  max-width: 440px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

#billing-title{
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#add-button{

  background-color: #4FEB75;
}

.billing-buttons{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  width: 136px;
  height: 30px; 
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#delete-button{
  background-color: #F5576C;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="shipping-section"></div>
    <form id="shipping-form">
            <div id="shipping-title-wrapper">
                <img src="Profiles Icon.svg" id="shipping-icon"></img>
                    <h2 id="shipping-title">Shipping</h2>
                </div>
        <input class="input-element left" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name"></input>
        <input class="input-element right" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
        <input class="input-element left full-length" id="email-address" placeholder="Email Address"></input>
        <input class="input-element left full-length" id="adress-line-1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></input>
        <input class="input-element left full-length" id="address-line-2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></input>
        <input class="input-element left" id="house-name" placeholder="House Name/Num"></input>
        <input class="input-element right" id="country-name" placeholder="Country"></input>
        <input class="input-element left" id="city-name" placeholder="City/State"></input>
        <input class="input-element right" id="postcode-name" placeholder="Postcode/Zipcode"></input>

        <div>
                <button class="billing-buttons" id="add-button">Add</button>
                <button class="billing-buttons" id="delete-button">Delete</button>
            </div>

    </form>

</div>



<div id="billing-form">
        <form id="shipping-form">
                <div id="shipping-title-wrapper">
                    <img src="Billing Icon.svg" id="shipping-icon"></img>
                        <h2 id="billing-title">Billing</h2>
                    </div>
            <input class="input-element left" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="email-address" placeholder="Email Address"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="adress-line-1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="address-line-2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></input>
            <input class="input-element left" id="house-name" placeholder="House Name/Num"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="country-name" placeholder="Country"></input>
            <input class="input-element left" id="city-name" placeholder="City/State"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="postcode-name" placeholder="Postcode/Zipcode"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="card-name" placeholder="Card Name"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="card-number" placeholder="Card Number"></input>
            <input class="input-element left" id="exp-date" placeholder="Exp Date (MM/YY)"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="exp-date" placeholder="CVV"></input>







        </form>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that none of the HTML elements on the page are functioning correctly, I.E I can't click on the input fields and cannot click on the buttons. The styling has also gone all wrong, the two forms used to sit side by side, before I tried adding a new form to a seperate page. I know I've probably done something stupid but spent hours trying to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Add the 'type' attribute to the input elements. e.g. <input type="text" .../> might do the trick.

Comment: Duplicate IDs are invalid.

Comment: Seems fine. You probably have some element overlaying the form. Have you inspected the document with dev tools? https://jsfiddle.net/h8orgkj3/

Comment: @Maurice, `text` is the default in HTML5 documents.

Comment: Tom, I'm voting to close as off-topic (can't reproduce). Please modify my fiddle to demonstrate the problem and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="shipping-section"></div>
```

Because shipping-section is closed here, and no width attribute specified in your form, it assumes 100% width. Try wrapping your shipping form in the shipping-section container.

Your forms aren't floating side by side because of their widths and margins.

And your text colour for the input is black meaning it is not visible against the input field background. Try changing it to white

See below for working code

```
<html>
<style>
/* SHIPPING FORM 
===============================================================================================
*/
::placeholder{
  font-weight: 600;
}

#shipping-section {
width: 40%;
float: left;
}
#shipping-form{
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width: 440px;
}

.input-element{
  background-color: #0C0C0D !important;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.full-length{
  width: 440px !important;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}
.right{
  float: right;
}

#shipping-title{
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#shipping-title-wrapper{
  margin-left: 170px;
}

#shipping-icon{
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

/* BILLING FORM 
===============================================================================================
*/

#billing-form{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: 40%;
}

#billing-title{
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#add-button{

  background-color: #4FEB75;
}

.billing-buttons{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  width: 136px;
  height: 30px; 
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#delete-button{
  background-color: #F5576C;
}
</style>


<div id="shipping-section">
    <form id="shipping-form">
            <div id="shipping-title-wrapper">
                <img src="Profiles Icon.svg" id="shipping-icon"></img>
                    <h2 id="shipping-title">Shipping</h2>
                </div>
        <input class="input-element left" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name"></input>
        <input class="input-element right" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
        <input class="input-element left full-length" id="email-address" placeholder="Email Address"></input>
        <input class="input-element left full-length" id="adress-line-1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></input>
        <input class="input-element left full-length" id="address-line-2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></input>
        <input class="input-element left" id="house-name" placeholder="House Name/Num"></input>
        <input class="input-element right" id="country-name" placeholder="Country"></input>
        <input class="input-element left" id="city-name" placeholder="City/State"></input>
        <input class="input-element right" id="postcode-name" placeholder="Postcode/Zipcode"></input>

        <div>
                <button class="billing-buttons" id="add-button">Add</button>
                <button class="billing-buttons" id="delete-button">Delete</button>
            </div>

    </form>

</div>



<div id="billing-form">
        <form id="shipping-form">
                <div id="shipping-title-wrapper">
                    <img src="Billing Icon.svg" id="shipping-icon"></img>
                        <h2 id="billing-title">Billing</h2>
                    </div>
            <input class="input-element left" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="email-address" placeholder="Email Address"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="adress-line-1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="address-line-2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></input>
            <input class="input-element left" id="house-name" placeholder="House Name/Num"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="country-name" placeholder="Country"></input>
            <input class="input-element left" id="city-name" placeholder="City/State"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="postcode-name" placeholder="Postcode/Zipcode"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="card-name" placeholder="Card Name"></input>
            <input class="input-element left full-length" id="card-number" placeholder="Card Number"></input>
            <input class="input-element left" id="exp-date" placeholder="Exp Date (MM/YY)"></input>
            <input class="input-element right" id="exp-date" placeholder="CVV"></input>







        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are getting confused with not being clickable and not being able to see the data entered

your background of your input fields are very dark

change your input-element class to

```
   .input-element{
      background-color: #0C0C0D !important;
      height: 30px;
      width: 200px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: none;
      padding: 15px;
      z-index: 1;
      color: white;
    }
```

I've added color:white to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/taz8vhoc/

once you add

```
color: white;
```

it works just fine